# How to write a C program to find maximum between three numbers using switch statement?

Tags: c, switch-statement, max

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3;
    printf("Enter three integers to find maximum: \n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", num1, num2, num3);
    switch (num1 > num2)
    {
        switch (num1 > num3)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("%d is maximum", num1);
            break;
            switch (num2 > num1)
            {
                switch (num2 > num3)
                {
                case 1:
                    printf("%d is maximum", num2);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("%d is maximum", num3);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `switch` statement program I wrote in VS Code to find maximum between 3 numbers, but it doesn't work. I declared 3 variables `num1`, `num2`, `num3` then I compared `num1` to `num2` and `num3`, Similarly `num2` to `num1` and `num3`, `num3` is in `default`.

Can we write maximum between 3 numbers?

Comment: You should be using `if`, not `switch`.

Comment: Using `switch` is perverse (but might be mandated by the course requirements for this exercise).  `int max = num1; if (num2 > max) max = num2; if (num3 > max) max = num3; print("%d is maximum\n", max);` is more sensible, and generalizes to four or more variables, or to an array of values.  Any solution with `switch` is going to cause trouble when trying to generalize the code.

Comment: There's the one and only true solution: `switch(num1) { case INT_MIN: case INT_MIN + 1: ... case INT_MAX - 1: case INT_MAX: }` and for each case the same nested for `num2` and finally again the same for `num3` – of course you need to cover via conditional compilation (`#if`/`#endif`) different sizes of `int` on different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

There are missing `case` or `default` clauses in your `switch` statement bodies.

Note also that you must pass the addresses of the target variables to `scanf()` and you should test that this `scanf` succeeded at converting 3 integers: it returns the number of successful conversions.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1, num2, num3;

    printf("Enter three integers to find maximum: \n");

    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3) != 3) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    switch (num1 > num2) {
    case 1:
        switch (num1 > num3) {
        case 1:
            printf("%d is maximum\n", num1);
            break;
        default:
            printf("%d is maximum\n", num3);
            break;
        }
    default:
        switch (num2 > num3) {
        case 1:
            printf("%d is maximum\n", num2);
            break;
        default:
            printf("%d is maximum\n", num3);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is an alternative with a single `switch` statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1, num2, num3;

    printf("Enter three integers to find maximum: \n");

    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3) != 3) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    switch ((num1 >= num2) + 2 * (num1 >= num3) + 4 * (num2 >= num3)) {
    case 3:
    case 7:
        printf("%d is maximum\n", num1);
        break;
    case 4:
    case 6:
        printf("%d is maximum\n", num2);
        break;
    case 0:
    case 1:
        printf("%d is maximum\n", num3);
        break;
    default:
        printf("CPU is broken\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, abusing the rules, here is a simplified version still using a `switch` statement, that is easy to extend to a larger set of numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1, num2, num3, max;

    printf("Enter three integers to find maximum: \n");

    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3) != 3) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    switch (max = num1,
            max = (max >= num2) * max + (max < num2) * num2,
            max = (max >= num3) * max + (max < num3) * num3)
    {
    default:
        printf("%d is maximum\n", max);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For completeness, the `switch` statement here above can be rewritten with an empty body:

```
    switch (max = num1,
            max = (max >= num2) * max + (max < num2) * num2,
            max = (max >= num3) * max + (max < num3) * num3)
        /* empty body */;

    printf("%d is maximum\n", max);
```

Comment: Second approach: 5 should be 6, 5 would be n1 >= n2 >= n3 <-> n1 < n3...

Comment: @Aconcagua: absolutely! this horrible thing is a pain to figure in ones head.

Comment: Actually not that much once you recognise a pattern; there are always two that must (not) apply while the remaining one is irrelevant, defining the offset, so +1+2*4 for num1, -1+4*2 for num2 and -2-4*1 for num3 (+: ==true, -: == false, *: any) ;)

Answer (score 2):

For starters the arguments of this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d%d%d", num1, num2, num3);
```

are incorrect. You need to write

```
scanf("%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
```

And in general you should check whether the input was successful as for example

```
if ( scanf("%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3) == 3 )
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

Secondly the user can enter at least two equal each other numbers that are gretaer than the third number. You have to take that into account.

To make it simpler to write switch statements it will be useful to perform the task using if statements. They can look the following way

```
    if (!( num1 < num2 ) && !( num1 < num3 ))
    {
        printf( "%d is maximum\n", num1 );
    }
    else if ( !( num2 < num3 ) )
    {
        printf( "%d is maximum\n", num2 );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%d is maximum\n", num3 );
    }
```

So now it is not hard to rewrite the if statements using switch statements. They can look the following way

```
    switch (!( num1 < num2 ) && !( num1 < num3 ))
    {
    case 1:
        printf( "%d is maximum\n", num1 );
        break;

    case 0:
        switch (!( num2 < num3 ))
        {
        case 1:
            printf( "%d is maximum\n", num2 );
            break;

        case 0:
            printf( "%d is maximum\n", num3 );
            break;
        }
    }
```

Instead of using the constants `0` and `1` in the case labels you can use named constants `false` and `true` by means of including header `<stdbool.h>` as for example

```
#include <stdbool.h>

//...

    switch (!( num1 < num2 ) && !( num1 < num3 ))
    {
    case true:
        printf( "%d is maximum\n", num1 );
        break;

    case false:
        switch (!( num2 < num3 ))
        {
        case true:
            printf( "%d is maximum\n", num2 );
            break;

        case false:
            printf( "%d is maximum\n", num3 );
            break;
        }
    }
```

Of course there are other ways to write the switch statements but this way is enough clear.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main( void )
{
    int num1, num2, num3;

    printf( "Enter three integers to find maximum: " );
    scanf( "%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3 );

    if (!( num1 < num2 ) && !( num1 < num3 ))
    {
        printf( "%d is maximum\n", num1 );
    }
    else if ( !( num2 < num3 ) )
    {
        printf( "%d is maximum\n", num2 );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%d is maximum\n", num3 );
    }

    switch (!( num1 < num2 ) && !( num1 < num3 ))
    {
    case true:
        printf( "%d is maximum\n", num1 );
        break;

    case false:
        switch (!( num2 < num3 ))
        {
        case true:
            printf( "%d is maximum\n", num2 );
            break;

        case false:
            printf( "%d is maximum\n", num3 );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter three integers to find maximum: 3 2 3
3 is maximum
3 is maximum
```

The if statements are included in the demonstration program only to show that the results of using if statements and switch statements will be the same. Of course in your program you should remove the if statements.

Comment: `!(x < y)` instead of `x >= y` looks pretty odd to me ;)

Comment: Requires three comparisons in worst case, could be done with maximally two of...